# Styling GridLines on ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, itemscontrol

As of now on my calender, a border is onlyplaced around the textblocks(dates) that are needed for that month. I have a grid that has 7 columns and  6 rows so thats 42 cells. A month only has max 31days(cells) so I have a lot of empty cells that dont have a border around it. How can I change this so that all 42 cells has a border around it making it look how a calender should look. Thanks in advance. :)

```xml
<Grid Name="controlGrid" Margin="0,56,0,0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
    <ColumnDefinition Width="86*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="83*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding schedule}" 
                Name="Calender"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
                Margin="0,-8,0,0">

    <ItemsControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl" >
        <Border BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" BorderThickness="3">
          <ItemsPresenter/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Name="gridCalender">
          <Grid.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
              <GradientStop Color="#FFC3D6F5" Offset="0" />
              <GradientStop Color="#FFEFF5FF" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
          </Grid.Background>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue">
          <TextBlock OpacityMask="Black"  Name="txtBlockdays">
            <Button Content="{Binding day}"
                    Width="175"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Name="btnCalenderDate"
                    Click="btnCalenderDate_Click"
                    Loaded="btnCalenderDate_Loaded"
                    Height="18"
                    FontSize="10"
                    FontWeight="Bold">
            </Button>
          </TextBlock>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style >
        <Setter  Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding WeekDay}"  />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding WeekNo}" />
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
      </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the code found [here](http://blog.saraf.me/2011/03/change-color-thickness-of-grid-lines.html) before which extends the `Grid` control to include properties that allow you to specify GridLine visibility, thickness, and color

```
<local:GridEx ShowCustomGridLines="True" 
              GridLineBrush="#FF38B800" 
              GridLineThickness="2">
    ...
</local:GridEx>
```

In case that link goes dead, here's the code:

```
public class GridControl : Grid
{
    #region Properties
    public bool ShowCustomGridLines
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCustomGridLinesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowCustomGridLinesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomGridLinesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCustomGridLines", typeof(bool), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public Brush GridLineBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridLineBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridLineBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLineBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridLineBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public double GridLineThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(GridLineThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridLineThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLineThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridLineThickness", typeof(double), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0));
    #endregion

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        if (ShowCustomGridLines)
        {
            foreach (var rowDefinition in RowDefinitions)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Point(0, rowDefinition.Offset), new Point(ActualWidth, rowDefinition.Offset));
            }

            foreach (var columnDefinition in ColumnDefinitions)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Point(columnDefinition.Offset, 0), new Point(columnDefinition.Offset, ActualHeight));
            }
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
        }
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
    static GridControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridControl)));
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds good but I'm getting all kinds of errors saying dependencyProperty could not found. Asking if I'm missing a assembly reference or directive?

Comment: never even heard of dependencyProperty until just now.

Comment: @TMan All WPF properties that you can bind to are `DependencyProperties`. They're properties that depend on another value. What that link does is create a Grid, but with some extra properties that you can bind to. The namespace for `DependencyProperty` is `System.Windows`

Comment: ok one more thing how(or do I need) to set up xmlns in the XAML? In other words how can I access the gridcontrol on xaml?

Comment: I need to keep resources, is the link you provided me(The URl) the original source so that I can give proper credit?

Comment: @TMan No idea, that's the link that someone else provided to me when I had the same question

Comment: @Andreas I've updated my answer with a good link and a copy of the code

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra dummy items to fill the other cells...

Comment: I though of that..I just don't know how I would do that

Comment: Add extra items to the `schedule` collection.

Comment: Yea I can't figure it out. This is my first wpf project, so I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Well, at some point I assume you're filling the `schedule` collection you're binding to?

Comment: Yea, the setter property is set to grid.row and grid.column.(the value is binded to properties of the schedule). By getting the week of the month and the day of the week, thats how I'm able to place the txtblocks where they belong. So I need an x,y coordinate value to create the calender for the specified month. So whatever I put in the DataTemplate will just be set to the gridcells that are required.

Comment: If I try to set the property Grid.row or Grid.Column value to an extra item, it messes up b/c then that value is being set more than once. It's hard to explain. ItemsControl's seems to be limited to what I'm allowed to do when it comes to adding and styling controls

Comment: No, you need to add items with WeekDay and WeekNo properties; you don't need to set Grid.Row and Grid.Column explicitly, since they are defined by bindings